# Login with GET API

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

Here is what I have tried.  This connects to the fornt page of the website, but I am unable to figure out how to get it to login.

```
Sub SendAPIrequest()

    Dim HTTPreq As Object, url As String, response As String, object As String
    
    Set HTTPreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    object = ""
    
    url = "my url" & object
    
    With HTTPreq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
    End With
    
    response = HTTPreq.responseText
    Debug.Print response

End Sub
```